# Alternatives to FT232H for USB to SPI communcation

Tags: usb, spi, ftdi, performance

For my current use case, I am using FT232H as a general purpose device that changes my USB packets into SPI information as an SPI controller for my SPI peripheral. My SPI peripheral can support upto 50Mhz clock speed.

1. FT232H has a max clock speed of 30Mhz
2. The libMPSSEengine that is written by FTDI is quite ancient and seems to have a INFRA_DELAY(2) which causes significant delays when I am toggling the CS pin as described here [FT232HL FTDI consecutive SPI bytes delay problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380531/ft232hl-ftdi-consecutive-spi-bytes-delay-problem)
3. USB 2 Buffering and general performance

Given these 3 concerns, I can hack 2 and 3 by interesting buffering solutions. Is there any alternative chips i should consider that is as simple as FT232H to use that can give me the full 50Mhz signal. The reason I feel it is important is that extra 66% speed boost for each data transfer can improve my buffering system. And preferably that uses USB 3/3.1 specification for a plausibly lower latencies.

I have googled several chips and am not able to find a suitable alternative. Suggestions like Raspberry Pi has all been tested (it has an Max SPI speed of 500 Khz, and i get a practical 300 Khz).

Comment: Use an MCU and move a bigger part of the task to it so that you send only bulk data and not specific operations over USB.  What exactly that means will depend on the nature of your application, but try to get anything where *latency* matters contained on one side of the USB not split across it.

Comment: 50MHz (1/20ns) is blazing fast in the SPI world; it's going to be hard to find any low-cost generic solution -- maybe a microcontroller or FPGA integrating USB and SPI specific to your device. Design/development costs will increase for that type of solution though. (FT232H is essentially a USB microcontroller, mask-programmed to support their MPSEE command codes, and because it's old the NRE costs are all paid off.) For FPGA design, a 50MHz (1/20ns) clock is easy, 100MHz (1/10ns) gets harder, and 200MHz (1/5ns) requires careful clock domain design and some manual guidance.

Comment: FTDI make many other USB chips, some with much higher speed. If you can't find a faster SPI one, then consider if it's worth combining a more generic one with a small FPGA to do the SPI side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not afraid of FPGAs you could buy a prototyping board, which has a USB bridge IC built in. There are some which have a FT2232H on them, which can be set to FIFO mode. It is able to achieve up to 40 Mbytes/s. But first and formost one can achieve very precise timing with a FPGA as intermediate controller. BTW, the latency for a round trip (i.e. data go back and forth) can be <1.3 ms if a FT2232H is properly set up and used.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go faster that the generic FTDI USB chip allows, the answer is a microcontroller, perhaps an existing $20 eval board for which you need to write custom firmware to make it a USB to SPI bridge. Or you can buy a ready made USB SPI host adapter from various vendors but these can be more than $200 as they are professional tools.

Comment: any particular boards or chips that you suggest?

Comment: No, because suggesting and asking what to buy is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with USB 2.0 (<50MHz) then you can look at some of the microchip solutions.

https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/MCP2210DataS.pdf

Comment: I think you mean USB full speed, since USB2.0 typically refers to USB high speed (480mbps)

Comment: Thanks! My mistake.